# C++ headers can not be accessed

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, header-files, bulletphysics

When trying to include some headers (from bullet libraries) I always get an error:

> fatal error: btBulletCollisionCommon.h: No such file or directory.

The reason is that it will not access the folder /usr/include/bullet/.
Just adding "bullet/btBulletCollisionCommon.h" doesn't solve this problem long term since inside it requests access to other headers and so on.

Is there a way to solve this in Ubuntu 16.04?

I suppose just taking all files from inside the /usr/include/bullet folder and putting them directly into /usr/include would solve it, but I am not sure how to do it in a fail-safe manner.

Comment: First of all, you have installed the development package of the library, i.e. the header files are really there in `/usr/include`? Secondly, how do you build your application, and what flags do you pass to the compiler when building?

Comment: How are you compiling? If you are using g++, you will need to add the include directory to the command line with    `-I /usr/include/bullet/`

Comment: Are you using "" or <> to specify the header file, if "" then the path is relative to the source file its included in, if <> then the compiler will use environment variables to search for the file.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.2 (tried with QtCreator also). Up until now, I didn't have any problems with access to libraries. The include method used is:
#include <btBulletCollisionCommon.h>.
Also I am running the code inside of the IDE's console, and the compiler is g++.

Comment: @MartinV any IDE will allow you to configure include directories. These directories will be passed along to the compiler, telling it where to search for header files. I'm not super familiar with newer NetBeans - it looks like the configuration might be in Project properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> General.

Comment: I did that again now, and the same problem persists. Is it possible to be an access problem?  The current program is "Hello world" with <iostream> and <btBulletCollisionCommon.h> and it still fails to execute.Because NetBeans can locate the headers (they appear with autocomplete) but says they don't exist at execution.

Comment: Somewhere in your project settings (I don't know NetBeans or QtCreator well enough to say exactly where) you should have some "Preprocessor settings" (or similar). There you should be able to add directories where the compiler should look for header files (it will be passed to the compiler using the `-I` (upper-case i) option). That list need to include the directory where `btBulletCollisionCommon.h` is located (presumably `/usr/include/bullet`).

Comment: Most IDE's also have options or similar to see the full command-lines used when calling the compiler, including all options. Try to find that option and make sure that e.g. `-I/usr/include/bullet` is used.

Comment: So somehow I managed to do it by manually adding them to the C++ compiler include directories, but also in the project's properties as directories to look at. Not sure why, but this was the only way to make it work.